# Where I can download LINQ to SQL Debug Visualizer plugin for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-addins

On Scott blog, he publish a plugin [LINQ to SQL Debug Visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx).

However, it only runs on Visual Studio 2008. I try it on Visual Studio 2010 but error.
Please help me to find a version 2010 or a similar plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if it's available for visual studio 2010 at all.

As far as I'm aware of, the Linq to SQL development has been suspended in favor of the entity framework. ( Please correct me if I'm wrong.. )